# Playing Multiple Lands in One Turn

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I know that for the most part you can only play one land per turn. However I also know that it is possible to put multiple lands onto the field with the effects of certain spells. I want to know if there are any limitations or certain situations where you cannot do this. I am especially curious about lands that have a tap ability to add land to your mana pool (such as [New Benalia](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Discussion.aspx?multiverseid=376428) or [Boros Guildgate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376272)). Can I play a land from my hand and use their abilities to get two land per turn?

Comment: For a situation where a spell lets you put one or more lands onto the battlefield but you can't actually do it, see [Worms of the Earth](http://magiccards.info/dk/en/18.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Cards don't "add land to your mana pool." They add *mana* to your mana pool.** The little symbols in card text and casting costs represent mana, which you get from tapping your lands (or from other cards like [Elvish Mystic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elvish%20Mystic), [Darksteel Ingot](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Ingot), and [Seething Song](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Seething%20Song)), not the lands themselves.

[New Benalia](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=New%20Benalia)'s ability, "{T}: Add {W} to your mana pool," is actually the same as the ability of a basic Plains card.

From the Comprehensive Rules:

> 305.6. The basic land types are Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, and Forest. If an object uses the
> words “basic land type,” it’s referring to one of these subtypes. A land with a basic land type has
> the intrinsic ability “{T}: Add [mana symbol] to your mana pool,” even if the text box doesn’t
> actually contain that text or the object has no text box. For Plains, [mana symbol] is {W}; for
> Islands, {U}; for Swamps, {B}; for Mountains, {R}; and for Forests, {G}.

If you have New Benalia and a Plains on the battlefield, you can tap both to make two white mana (like the casting cost for a [Precinct Captain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Precinct%20Captain)), just like if you had two Plains.

Cards that actually put more land into play say things like "Search your library for a basic land card and put that card onto the battlefield tapped" or "You may play an additional land this turn" (e.g. [Evolving Wilds](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Evolving%20Wilds) and [Explore](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Explore)).

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. I was very confused and this makes a lot more sense than what I thought the card was used for.

Comment: @AdamP For what it's worth, this is actually a pretty common point of confusion for beginning players.

Comment: Does anyone know why they changed Plains from having T:Add W to your mana pool to just a picture of a giant W mana symbol? It seems to cause a lot of confusion!

Comment: The text "Tap to add {W} to your mana pool" was the original text, changed to "{T}: Add {W} to your mana pool" in 3nd edition, and was removed in favor of the giant mana symbols in 6th edition. Have no idea why though.

Comment: it looked cooler.

Comment: I also think adding something about Evolving Wilds/Terramorphic Expanse would be good here, since they are lands that add to your land pool. :)

Comment: There's actually another reason. The tap ability became inherent to the Basic Land type, so the rule text became flavour text. (this allows stuff like "target land becomes a Mountain" to work as expected)